# How to connect API from PowerShell with OAUTH 2.0?

Tags: powershell, api

I am new in powershell, I need to connect to an API that has OAUTH2.0 authentication, the API generates a file in json format.

If I run the script from POWESHELL ISE it works correctly, it authenticates and downloads a json file

```
$application = "https://api.xxxx.com/token";
$username = "myuser";

$password = "mypassword";

$creds = @{
    username = $username
    password = $password
    grant_type = "password"    
};

$header_token = @{"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
$header_Out = @{"Accept" = "application/json" ; "authorization" = "bearer $token"}

$datestart = (Get-Date).addDays(-1).tostring(“yyyy-MM-dd”)
$dateend = (Get-Date).addDays(-1).tostring(“yyyy-MM-dd”)

$response = Invoke-RestMethod "$application" -Method Post -Body $creds -Headers $headers;

$token = $response.access_token;

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.xxxx.com/api/TrafficData/Hourly?from=$datestart&to=$dateend" -Header $header_Out -OutFile "G:\Traffic.json"
$host.enternestedprompt()
```

but if i run it from ps1 file it generates authentication error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksccb.png)

Anyone know what might be happening?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please copy /past the error as a text and remove the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand it works on ISE because you develop it inside ISE in the first  attempt you give a value to `$token` that was kept in the session for the second attempt.

Can you just try to add the line in comment ?

```
$application = "https://api.xxxx.com/token";
$username = "myuser";

$password = "mypassword";

$creds = @{
    username = $username
    password = $password
    grant_type = "password"    
};

$header_token = @{"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
$header_Out = @{"Accept" = "application/json" ; "authorization" = "bearer $token"}

$datestart = (Get-Date).addDays(-1).tostring(“yyyy-MM-dd”)
$dateend = (Get-Date).addDays(-1).tostring(“yyyy-MM-dd”)

$response = Invoke-RestMethod "$application" -Method Post -Body $creds -Headers $header_token

$token = $response.access_token;
# JPB : Here, you receive the token so you use it
$header_Out = @{"Accept" = "application/json" ; "authorization" = "bearer $token"}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.xxxx.com/api/TrafficData/Hourly?from=$datestart&to=$dateend" -Header $header_Out -OutFile "G:\Traffic.json"
$host.enternestedprompt()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was using the token before loading the response into the variable. it works now.

Comment: I'm confused.  You use the `$headers` variable, but it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I just copy the code from the question because the trouble was not there, so I think you add to replace `$headers` by `$header_token` . I edit my answer this way.