# How can I authenticate a user without using the password grant_type in an OAuth flow?

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0, clientcredential, oauth-2.1

As I read OAuth 2.0 recommends against using the `password` grant type and it is being removed in the OAuth 2.1 update. But what is the proper solution then when you have a machine-to-machine communication channel?

In my case I have a couple of Powershell scripts that get an access token used in subsequent API calls. So they are requesting an access token by providing the username and password of my applicative user which has its own claims and thus gets access to a limited set of API's.

I could use a `client_credentials` flow instead, but then I am not authenticating an actual batch user, just my client. Which might not give me the claims I am looking for. And as a follow-up question, how is hardcoding the client id + secret any different from hardcoding the user + password?

Comment: Use Credentials where the password is encrypted and get the token.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125283/how-to-connect-api-from-powershell-with-oauth-2-0

Comment: @jdweng That is pretty much what I am doing already, but the password grant_type is going to be removed in OAuth 2.1. So I would need another flow to authenticate a user without using the password grant_type.

Comment: See example of request here.  The code is in json and can easily be converted to powershell. https://connect2id.com/learn/oauth-2-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `client credentials flow` is the correct option for backend initiated flows, such as a scheduled job, when no user is involved.

Alternatively, if your scripts are run interactively by  admin users, a [native code flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-7.3) could be used by the script, which is a console (native) client. Doing so could issue different claims based on the script user.

Regardless of the flow you can still use claims. The client's `scope` triggers inclusion of the claims. Issuing claims doesn't have to involve a user.

As an example, consider a nightly job that checks for unpaid invoices. This could use a scope like `invoices:reconcile` that isn't used by any other client. Using this scope might also trigger inclusion of claims such as `region=USA`, where the claims are calculated based on some logic applied at the time of token issuance.

Some authorization servers may have limitations on how claims are issued for the client credentials flow, meaning you may need to resort to workarounds. There is no such limitation in OAuth 2.0 itself though, so I always like to encourage the most standards based designs.

**CLIENT CREDENTIALS FLOW**

It is possible to use one of these methods for the client credentials flow, that supports multiple callers, with only a single client registration. Based on properties received, different claims can be issued:

- Client assertion credentials, with different properties per caller
- Client certificate credentials, with different properties per caller

Separate clients is usually recommended though. It ensures that, if client A's credential is compromised, you can can deny access without affecting client B.

Comment: Thanks for your clear response. Indeed you can issue claims based on the client, but that means that now you will need an additional client in case you want to have different claim values. Whereas before I could use one client and have different users. It's not clear to me why the password flow is deprecated now, as both flows will have hardcoded passwords in the script (user/password or client/secret).

Comment: The client credentials flow can use stronger credentials, like client assertions or client certificates. The password flow is deprecated for user based apps, partly because it prevents clients from using any other method, and also because in many cases the user's password should not be revealed to the client.

Comment: I also added a section to my answer on multiple callers with the client credentials flow.