# Publish-Module raises 401 when using GitHub action

Tags: powershell, nuget

I try to publish a module with an github action to the github package directory by using the Publish-Module cmdlet. I sue a Windows Server 2022, with a blank installation where the github action runner is installed on.

The section in my github workflow is the following:

```yaml
jobs:
  pwslmanage:
    name: pswslmanage
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    permissions:
      actions: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          path: ./pswslmanage

      - name: Publish
        run: |
          $_repo_name = "SAPSGallery"
          $_repo_owner = "myorg"
          $_feed = "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/$_repo_owner/index.json"
          $_user = "user-myorg"
          $_token = "$($env:GH_TOKEN)" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
          $_creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($_user, $_token)
          $_module_name = "pswslmanage"
          $_repo_dir = "{0}\myorg-pswslmanage\pswslmanage" -f $($env:RUNNER_WORKSPACE)

          Register-PSRepository -Name $_repo_name -SourceLocation $_feed -PublishLocation $_feed -InstallationPolicy 'Trusted' -Credential $_creds -Verbose
          Publish-Module -Path "$_repo_dir" -Repository "$_repo_name" -NuGetApiKey "$($env:GH_TOKEN)" -Verbose
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

What ever i try, get an error `Unable to load the service index for source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/index.json. 401 (Unauthorized)`. I tested that with Powershell 5.1 as well as PSCore 7.3.6. Below you will the VERBOSE output of the Publish-Module as well (but only the alst few lines are interesting i think).

I tried to download the index.json in the browser with the given GH_TOKEN (and a random username) which works. I also tries to use a PAT with full privileges (instead of the build-in token provided by secret.GITHUB_TOKEN).

Edit: "TLS1.3" must be disabled and "nuget" must be downloaded to "$($env:PROGRAMDATA)\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PowerShellGet" to get to the point where the 401 error occures.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Dave

```
VERBOSE: Acquiring providers for assembly: C:\program files\powershell\7\Modules\PackageManagement\coreclr\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PackageManagement.NuGetProvider.dll 
VERBOSE: Acquiring providers for assembly: C:\program files\powershell\7\Modules\PackageManagement\coreclr\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PackageManagement.MetaProvider.PowerShell.dll 
VERBOSE: Acquiring providers for assembly: C:\program files\powershell\7\Modules\PackageManagement\coreclr\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PackageManagement.ArchiverProviders.dll 
VERBOSE: Acquiring providers for assembly: C:\program files\powershell\7\Modules\PackageManagement\coreclr\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PackageManagement.CoreProviders.dll 
VERBOSE: Suppressed Verbose Repository details, Name = 'SAPSGallery', Location = 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/index.json'; IsTrusted = 'True'; IsRegistered = 'True'. 
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'SAPSGallery', Location = 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/index.json'; IsTrusted = 'True'; IsRegistered = 'True'. 
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'SAPSGallery', Location = 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/index.json'; IsTrusted = 'True'; IsRegistered = 'True'. 
VERBOSE: Publish Location:'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/index.json'. VERBOSE: Module 'pswslmanage' was found in 'C:\ProgramData\GitHub-Actions-Runner_work\myorg-pswslmanage\myorg-pswslmanage\pswslmanage'. 
VERBOSE: Suppressed Verbose Repository details, Name = 'SAPSGallery', Location = 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/index.json'; IsTrusted = 'True'; IsRegistered = 'True'. 
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'SAPSGallery', Location = 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/index.json'; IsTrusted = 'True'; IsRegistered = 'True'. 
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages. 
VERBOSE: Using the specified source names : 'SAPSGallery'. 
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'. 
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/index.json' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'. 
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/query' for '2' more times 
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/query' for '1' more times 
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/query' for '0' more times 
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/pswslmanage/index.json' for '0' more times 
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/pswslmanage/index.json' for '0' more times 
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/pswslmanage/index.json' for '0' more times 
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'0' for the specified package 'pswslmanage'. 
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Publish-Module" on target "Version '1.0.0' of module 'pswslmanage'". 
VERBOSE: Calling Publish-PSArtifactUtility VERBOSE: Calling New-NuspecFile VERBOSE: Calling New-NugetPackage 
VERBOSE: Calling C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PowerShellGet\NuGet.exe pack "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1989646393\pswslmanage\pswslmanage.nuspec" -outputdirectory "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1989646393\pswslmanage" -noninteractive 
VERBOSE: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PowerShellGet\NuGet.exe output: VERBOSE: Attempting to build package from 'pswslmanage.nuspec'. 
VERBOSE: WARNING: NU5119: File 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1989646393\pswslmanage.gitattributes' was not added to the package. Files and folders starting with '.' or ending with '.nupkg' are excluded by default. To include this file, use -NoDefaultExcludes from the commandline 
VERBOSE: WARNING: NU5119: File 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1989646393\pswslmanage.gitignore' was not added to the package. Files and folders starting with '.' or ending with '.nupkg' are excluded by default. To include this file, use -NoDefaultExcludes from the commandline 
VERBOSE: WARNING: NU5110: The script file 'pswslmanage-helper.ps1' is outside the 'tools' folder and hence will not be executed during installation of this package. Move it into the 'tools' folder. 
VERBOSE: WARNING: NU5110: The script file 'pswslmanage-roles.ps1' is outside the 'tools' folder and hence will not be executed during installation of this package. Move it into the 'tools' folder. 
VERBOSE: WARNING: NU5110: The script file 'pswslmanage-start.ps1' is outside the 'tools' folder and hence will not be executed during installation of this package. Move it into the 'tools' folder. 
VERBOSE: WARNING: NU5110: The script file 'tests\pswslmanage.tests.ps1' is outside the 'tools' folder and hence will not be executed during installation of this package. Move it into the 'tools' folder. 
VERBOSE: WARNING: NU5111: The script file 'pswslmanage-helper.ps1' is not recognized by NuGet and hence will not be executed during installation of this package. Rename it to install.ps1, uninstall.ps1 or init.ps1 and place it directly under 'tools'. 
VERBOSE: WARNING: NU5111: The script file 'pswslmanage-roles.ps1' is not recognized by NuGet and hence will not be executed during installation of this package. Rename it to install.ps1, uninstall.ps1 or init.ps1 and place it directly under 'tools'. 
VERBOSE: WARNING: NU5111: The script file 'pswslmanage-start.ps1' is not recognized by NuGet and hence will not be executed during installation of this package. Rename it to install.ps1, uninstall.ps1 or init.ps1 and place it directly under 'tools'. 
VERBOSE: WARNING: NU5111: The script file 'tests\pswslmanage.tests.ps1' is not recognized by NuGet and hence will not be executed during installation of this package. Rename it to install.ps1, uninstall.ps1 or init.ps1 and place it directly under 'tools'. 
VERBOSE: The package pswslmanage.1.0.0 is missing a readme. Go to https://aka.ms/nuget/authoring-best-practices/readme to learn why package readmes are important. 
VERBOSE: Successfully created package 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1989646393\pswslmanage\pswslmanage.1.0.0.nupkg'. 
VERBOSE: 
VERBOSE: finished running C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PowerShellGet\NuGet.exe with exit code 0 
VERBOSE: Created Nuget Package C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1989646393\pswslmanage\pswslmanage.1.0.0.nupkg 
VERBOSE: Successfully created nuget package at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1989646393\pswslmanage\pswslmanage.1.0.0.nupkg 
VERBOSE: Calling Publish-NugetPackage -NupkgPath C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1989646393\pswslmanage\pswslmanage.1.0.0.nupkg -Destination https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/index.json -NugetExePath C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PowerShellGet\NuGet.exe -UseDotnetCli:FalseWrite-Error: Failed to publish module 'pswslmanage': 'nuget.exe failed to push Unable to load the service index for source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myorg/index.json. Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). '.
```

Comment: The most important part of the posting is you code works with a browser and give an Unauthorize response with PS.  It looks like you are using OAUTH2 where you first request a token (cookie) and then sends the token with each request.  Error 401 can mean there is something wrong with either getting the token or adding the token to each request.  The browser will automatically do two request by getting the token and then the token with the request.  See following :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125283/how-to-connect-api-from-powershell-with-oauth-2-0

Comment: The important part of link above is : -Header $header_Out

Comment: Okay, i tried the following with the token i also use in the workflow:  

```powershell
$_headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$_headers.Add("Authorization", "token $_token")  
$_headers.Add("Accept", "application/json")  
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://nuget.pkg.github.com/shiftavenue/index.json -Headers $_headers  
```

That works fine

Comment: I was not able to format that. In short terms: I did an Invoke-Webrequest to download the index.json which works well.

Comment: Did you try to parse the contents (body) with ConvertFrom-Json

Comment: Works as well: `$_obj = ConvertFrom-Json $([String]::new($_response.Content))`

Comment: Have you read github's docs? They have a section specifically on authentication: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry#authenticating-to-github-packages

Comment: Yes i did. I tried to use the "secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN" variable and a PAT with all privileges given. Non of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have an half-answer as solution. Probably it will help someone to go further with that.

The v2-Powershell commands where not compatible with GitHub Packages. It is needed to install the v3-PSResourceGet commands together with the compatibility module "CompatPowerShellGet". I was successful by running the commands manually. I was able to Publish (`Publish-Module ...`) the module, to find (`Find-Module -Name pswslmanage -Repository SAPSGallery`) and to install the module (`Install-Module ...`) from the GitHub Packages.

But it is an half-answer because the same commands are not successful when running as GitHub action. This will produce the following output:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Publish-PSResource" on target "Publish resource 'C:\ProgramData\GitHub-Actions-Runner\_work\shiftavenue-pswslmanage\shiftavenue-pswslmanage\pswslmanage' from the machine".
VERBOSE: The newly created nuspec is: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\233a4e7a-ceca-4894-9705-9001f72f5585\pswslmanage.nuspec
VERBOSE: Successfully packed the resource into a .nupkg
VERBOSE: Not able to publish resource to 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/shiftavenue/index.json'
VERBOSE: Deleting temporary directory 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\233a4e7a-ceca-4894-9705-9001f72f5585'
Publish-PSResource: C:\ProgramData\GitHub-Actions-Runner\_work\_temp\5615f135-c32d-49aa-81ec-3147104bfb1c.ps1:39
Line |
  39 |  Publish-Module -Path "$_repo_dir" -Repository "$_repo_name" -NuGetApi …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Repository 'SAPSGallery': Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

M idea was to publish dev-releases to GitHub packages instead of the PSGallery. For now i will give up to that and publish to PSGallery with the Prerelease-Flag.