# Error while uploading a binary to StoreApp using API

Tags: powershell, windows-store-apps

I am trying to use Microsoft Partner Center APIs. Tried with below PowerShell script but getting error. Due to this, we are unable to use Microsoft Partner Center APIs so looking for help to fix this issue.

**Sample Code:**

```
$AzureADtenant = "XeroxDevelopment.onmicrosoft.com"
$AzureADtenantId = "xxxx"
$ClientId = "yyyy"
$ClientSecret = "zzzzz"
$resource = "https://partner.microsoft.com"
$requestAccessTokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$AzureADtenantid/oauth2/token"
$body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$ClientId&client_secret=$ClientSecret&resource=$resource"
$accessToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $requestAccessTokenUri -Body $body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

**Error:**

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":"server_error","error_description":"AADSTS50000: There was an error issuing a token or an issue with our sign-in service.\r\nTrace ID: 60c1365f-be7f-472a-87c8-fd03aa9b4a02\r\nCorrelation ID: 
d5422741-088d-4cad-9da8-fd6c4486fc94\r\nTimestamp: 2023-10-19 14:26:22Z","error_codes":[50000],"timestamp":"2023-10-19 
14:26:22Z","trace_id":"60c1365f-be7f-472a-87c8-fd03aa9b4a02","correlation_id":"d5422741-088d-4cad-9da8-fd6c4486fc94","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50000"}
At line:12 char:16
+ ... cessToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $requestAccessTokenUr ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodComm
```

Comment: What type of authentication are you using?  Most systems in the last few years have moved from Windows Credentials to OAUTH2.  OAUTH2 is supported in Windows, Mac, Linux.   The server looks like it is expecting a token which is OAUTH2.  OAUTH2 is a two part authentication where you first request a token and then sent a HTTP Request using the token.

Comment: We are trying to use Token based authentication mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/create-and-manage-submissions-using-windows-store-services#code-examples and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/publish/partner-center/associate-existing-azure-ad-tenant-with-partner-center-account and

Comment: First get token working.  You should get a 200 OK response when it is working.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125283/how-to-connect-api-from-powershell-with-oauth-2-0