Workfront API in Powershell
I am having a problem downloading documents from Workfront through the API, programming in Powershell. I am able to get the downloadURL and the download URL works when I'm logged in through my browser. However, when I try to use the URL in Powershell, it is not working.
I am running this command:
$downloadResponse = Curl -Uri $url -Header $header -Body $body -OutFile $downloadPath

I am providing an apiKey (I've tried in both $body and $header) in the CURL command in Powershell.
The $url variable contains something like this:
https://.my.workfront.com/internal/document/download?ID=abc123456def123456
I am getting the file, with the proper name, in the proper location. But, the file that is downloading is a 4k file (should be much larger), starting with this:
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
<noscript>
<p>
<strong>Note:</strong> Since your browser does not support JavaScript,
you must press the Continue button once to proceed.
</p>
</noscript>

I have done further reading that I need a sessionID as part of the download URL. It looks like I can't use an apiKey.
I have an OAuth2 application setup in Workfront, but I can't figure out how to use it. The call requires a JWT (JSON Web Token), but it keeps saying "invalid". I'm new to JWT so I'm not sure I'm creating it correctly.

I do not think this is an authentication issue.  OAUTH2 is a two step authentication.  Step 1 is to get a token/cookie.  If you are getting a 200 OK from step 1 this is not an not an authentication issue.  Error message indicates that the server you are connecting to has Java Scripts and the Java is not running so you are not getting the full response.  See following : https://www.finallot.com/companies/411b7763-b292-4a7a-9276-9cb7876b5ba6

I should have been clearer, when I got that response, it was when I supplying an apiKey, rather than using oauth2.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125283/how-to-connect-api-from-powershell-with-oauth-2-0
