Is it possible to run Connect-IPPSSession, Connect-ExchangeOnline using pwsh on a linux server?
I am trying to use the Powershell ExchangeOnlineManagement module, but I have to perform some automations on a Linux RedHat server and I would like to know if it is possible to execute commands like Connect-ExchangeOnline or Connect-IPPSSession using the PWSH package.

You need to use OAUTH2 credentials.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps#appendix-comparison-of-old-and-new-connection-methods and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125283/how-to-connect-api-from-powershell-with-oauth-2-0  Looks like OAUTH is obsolete with exchange to you may want to use other type credentials.
